# MySQL Crashed, Logs Have Many Errors, DB Possibly Corrupted

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, lamp

I run a LAMP server on Digital Ocean with a WordPress installation on it for a friend's website. I recently transferred it over from AWS. It crashed and I received the `Error establishing database connection` screen. I discovered that MySQL stopped running, so I restarted it. The site works now but I'm afraid it will crash again.

Here are the logs:

```
2019-02-11T12:46:04.647354Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-02-11T12:46:04.658710Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) starting as process 13178 ...
2019-02-11T12:46:04.683378Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2019-02-11T12:46:04.683423Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-02-11T12:46:04.683429Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-02-11T12:46:04.683434Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2019-02-11T12:46:04.683451Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-02-11T12:46:04.683484Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-02-11T12:46:04.684680Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-02-11T12:46:04.688086Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2019-02-11T12:46:04.701706Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2019-02-11T12:46:04.704353Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: mmap(137428992 bytes) failed; errno 12
2019-02-11T12:46:04.704377Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2019-02-11T12:46:04.704385Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2019-02-11T12:46:04.704394Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2019-02-11T12:46:04.704400Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2019-02-11T12:46:04.704412Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2019-02-11T12:46:04.704417Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2019-02-11T12:46:04.709129Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2019-02-11T12:46:04.709197Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2019-02-11T12:46:04.709559Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2019-02-11T12:46:05.385154Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-02-11T12:46:05.387281Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) starting as process 13213 ...
2019-02-11T12:46:05.400665Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2019-02-11T12:46:05.400710Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-02-11T12:46:05.400716Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-02-11T12:46:05.400722Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2019-02-11T12:46:05.400727Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-02-11T12:46:05.400732Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-02-11T12:46:05.401035Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-02-11T12:46:05.401165Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2019-02-11T12:46:05.405573Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2019-02-11T12:46:05.405629Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: mmap(137428992 bytes) failed; errno 12
2019-02-11T12:46:05.405641Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2019-02-11T12:46:05.405647Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2019-02-11T12:46:05.405654Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2019-02-11T12:46:05.405659Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2019-02-11T12:46:05.405665Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2019-02-11T12:46:05.405669Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2019-02-11T12:46:05.417138Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2019-02-11T12:46:05.417206Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2019-02-11T12:46:05.417535Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2019-02-11T12:46:06.132732Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-02-11T12:46:06.134944Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) starting as process 13252 ...
2019-02-11T12:46:06.148774Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2019-02-11T12:46:06.148814Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-02-11T12:46:06.150943Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-02-11T12:46:06.150956Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2019-02-11T12:46:06.150962Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-02-11T12:46:06.150967Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-02-11T12:46:06.151245Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-02-11T12:46:06.151365Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2019-02-11T12:46:06.153460Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2019-02-11T12:46:06.153515Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: mmap(137428992 bytes) failed; errno 12
2019-02-11T12:46:06.153525Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2019-02-11T12:46:06.153531Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2019-02-11T12:46:06.153538Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2019-02-11T12:46:06.153543Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2019-02-11T12:46:06.153549Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2019-02-11T12:46:06.153554Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2019-02-11T12:46:06.164914Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2019-02-11T12:46:06.164990Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2019-02-11T12:46:06.165331Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2019-02-11T12:46:06.886427Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-02-11T12:46:06.892617Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) starting as process 13291 ...
2019-02-11T12:46:06.927400Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2019-02-11T12:46:06.927480Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-02-11T12:46:06.927489Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-02-11T12:46:06.927495Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2019-02-11T12:46:06.927500Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-02-11T12:46:06.927505Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-02-11T12:46:06.932089Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-02-11T12:46:06.932332Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2019-02-11T12:46:06.960416Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2019-02-11T12:46:06.960486Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: mmap(137428992 bytes) failed; errno 12
2019-02-11T12:46:06.960497Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2019-02-11T12:46:06.960503Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2019-02-11T12:46:06.960513Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2019-02-11T12:46:06.960519Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2019-02-11T12:46:06.960525Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2019-02-11T12:46:06.960530Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2019-02-11T12:46:06.968342Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2019-02-11T12:46:06.968413Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2019-02-11T12:46:06.968749Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2019-02-11T12:46:07.630976Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-02-11T12:46:07.637157Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) starting as process 13330 ...
2019-02-11T12:46:07.646460Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2019-02-11T12:46:07.646495Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-02-11T12:46:07.646501Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-02-11T12:46:07.646506Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2019-02-11T12:46:07.646512Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-02-11T12:46:07.646517Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-02-11T12:46:07.646820Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-02-11T12:46:07.646953Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2019-02-11T12:46:07.657012Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2019-02-11T12:46:07.657071Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: mmap(137428992 bytes) failed; errno 12
2019-02-11T12:46:07.657082Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2019-02-11T12:46:07.657088Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2019-02-11T12:46:07.657096Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2019-02-11T12:46:07.657101Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2019-02-11T12:46:07.657108Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2019-02-11T12:46:07.657112Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2019-02-11T12:46:07.664501Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2019-02-11T12:46:07.664568Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2019-02-11T12:46:07.664907Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2019-02-11T18:30:32.001526Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-02-11T18:30:32.008096Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) starting as process 15177 ...
2019-02-11T18:30:32.020450Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2019-02-11T18:30:32.020488Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-02-11T18:30:32.020495Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-02-11T18:30:32.020501Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2019-02-11T18:30:32.020511Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-02-11T18:30:32.020517Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-02-11T18:30:32.021674Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-02-11T18:30:32.024458Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2019-02-11T18:30:32.027778Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2019-02-11T18:30:32.048894Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-02-11T18:30:32.052604Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2019-02-11T18:30:32.070698Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2019-02-11T18:30:32.074927Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 198219821
2019-02-11T18:30:32.074948Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 198219830
2019-02-11T18:30:32.074956Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2019-02-11T18:30:32.074962Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2019-02-11T18:30:32.284797Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-02-11T18:30:32.284833Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-02-11T18:30:32.284897Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-02-11T18:30:32.305918Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-02-11T18:30:32.307124Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-02-11T18:30:32.307146Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-02-11T18:30:32.307448Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-02-11T18:30:32.357698Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.25 started; log sequence number 198219830
2019-02-11T18:30:32.358000Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2019-02-11T18:30:32.358645Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2019-02-11T18:30:32.367822Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190211 18:30:32
2019-02-11T18:30:32.372021Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2019-02-11T18:30:32.372052Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2019-02-11T18:30:32.372069Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2019-02-11T18:30:32.372117Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2019-02-11T18:30:32.374574Z 0 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mysql/user' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2019-02-11T18:30:32.374807Z 0 [Warning] Checking table:   './mysql/user'
2019-02-11T18:30:32.374828Z 0 [ERROR] 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly
2019-02-11T18:30:32.376040Z 0 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mysql/db' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2019-02-11T18:30:32.376258Z 0 [Warning] Checking table:   './mysql/db'
2019-02-11T18:30:32.376276Z 0 [ERROR] 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly
2019-02-11T18:30:32.417495Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2019-02-11T18:30:32.417717Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
```

I looked up some of the errors and one suggestion said to setup a swapfile. I forgot to do that when I initially setup the server, but I've done it now. Is that enough to solve all these issues?

The logs say that a DB has crashed and should be repaired, but when I run `mysqlcheck -uroot -p --repair --all-databases`, I received an error:

> Warning  : Please do not modify the gtid_executed table. This is a mysql internal system table to store GTIDs for committed transactions. Modifying it can lead to an inconsistent GTID state

Additionally, almost all the databases return

> The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair

I'm not that great with MySQL, some help would be appreciated.

EDIT - ***
Here are my MySql logs after creating a swap file and following Pimp Juice IT's direction to copy and recreate mysql.user and mysql.db.

```
2019-02-14T01:11:32.323393Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) starting as process 13773 ...
2019-02-14T01:11:32.330267Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2019-02-14T01:11:32.330314Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-02-14T01:11:32.330320Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-02-14T01:11:32.330325Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2019-02-14T01:11:32.330331Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-02-14T01:11:32.330336Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-02-14T01:11:32.330711Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-02-14T01:11:32.331148Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2019-02-14T01:11:32.335469Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2019-02-14T01:11:32.349062Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-02-14T01:11:32.351877Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2019-02-14T01:11:32.367267Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2019-02-14T01:11:32.398365Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-02-14T01:11:32.398456Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-02-14T01:11:32.427196Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-02-14T01:11:32.428313Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-02-14T01:11:32.428334Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-02-14T01:11:32.428694Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-02-14T01:11:32.478973Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.25 started; log sequence number 235030084
2019-02-14T01:11:32.479462Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2019-02-14T01:11:32.479792Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2019-02-14T01:11:32.497280Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2019-02-14T01:11:32.497320Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2019-02-14T01:11:32.497341Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2019-02-14T01:11:32.497378Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2019-02-14T01:11:32.529140Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190214  1:11:32
2019-02-14T01:11:32.551263Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2019-02-14T01:11:32.551501Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
2019-02-14T01:12:57.820655Z 7 [Note] Access denied for user 'ryan'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2019-02-14T01:15:49.115479Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2019-02-14T01:15:49.115520Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2019-02-14T01:15:49.115529Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2019-02-14T01:15:49.115537Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2019-02-14T01:15:49.115660Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117415Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'auth_socket'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117434Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117438Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117443Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117448Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117464Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117501Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117506Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117513Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117517Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117521Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117524Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117527Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117531Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117534Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117537Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117540Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117544Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117547Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117550Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117553Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117557Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117560Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117563Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117566Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117570Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117573Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117576Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117580Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117583Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117586Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117590Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117593Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117596Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117599Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117603Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117606Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117609Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.117613Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2019-02-14T01:15:49.122626Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2019-02-14T01:15:49.122808Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2019-02-14T01:15:49.223291Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2019-02-14T01:15:49.223542Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 190214  1:15:49
2019-02-14T01:15:50.436146Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 235125993
2019-02-14T01:15:50.439129Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-02-14T01:15:50.439170Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2019-02-14T01:15:50.439181Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2019-02-14T01:15:50.439190Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2019-02-14T01:15:50.439195Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2019-02-14T01:15:50.439475Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2019-02-14T01:15:50.440036Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2019-02-14T01:15:50.777735Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-02-14T01:15:50.779938Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) starting as process 14025 ...
2019-02-14T01:15:50.785356Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2019-02-14T01:15:50.785392Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-02-14T01:15:50.785409Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-02-14T01:15:50.785415Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2019-02-14T01:15:50.785420Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-02-14T01:15:50.785425Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-02-14T01:15:50.785730Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-02-14T01:15:50.785867Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2019-02-14T01:15:50.790011Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2019-02-14T01:15:50.800479Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-02-14T01:15:50.803193Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2019-02-14T01:15:50.815660Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2019-02-14T01:15:50.832348Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-02-14T01:15:50.832440Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-02-14T01:15:50.852215Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-02-14T01:15:50.853258Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-02-14T01:15:50.853278Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-02-14T01:15:50.853589Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-02-14T01:15:50.903857Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.25 started; log sequence number 235125993
2019-02-14T01:15:50.904272Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2019-02-14T01:15:50.910678Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2019-02-14T01:15:50.910702Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2019-02-14T01:15:50.910720Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2019-02-14T01:15:50.910755Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2019-02-14T01:15:50.911679Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2019-02-14T01:15:50.914945Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190214  1:15:50
2019-02-14T01:15:50.923429Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2019-02-14T01:15:50.923699Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
```

I think everything is ok now. It was likely just a problem with memory. Thank you to Pimp Juice IT.

Comment: Apache is notorious for causing MySQL on the same machine to be killed in exactly this way.  https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/25165/11651 https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/25083/11651

Comment: An easy solution for this is to take a dump of the MySQL database, make note of the user credentials, uninstall MySQL and then reinstall it again, restore the database and restore the user credentials. Maybe make a copy of the `my.cnf` just in case. This is the most effective way to recover from something like this. Or simply copy the core MySQL database file binaries in `/var/lib/mysql`, uninstall MySQL, rein stall it and then copy over the database files to the new setup. Remember, stuff like this is scary but is still logically recoverable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **MySQL Started Option**

If you can connect to the MySQL instance even though the error message states the table  has crashed, you could copy the data from the existing tables to a  staging table, truncate the original system table, and then insert the records back into the original table from the staging table load.

> **Copy and Recreate the mysql.user table**
>
> ```
> create table mysql.new_user like mysql.user;
> insert mysql.new_user select * from mysql.user;
> truncate table mysql.user;
> insert mysql.user select * from mysql.new_user;
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **Copy and Recreate the mysql.db table**
>
> ```
> create table mysql.new_db like mysql.db;
> insert mysql.new_db select * from mysql.db;
> truncate table mysql.db;
> insert mysql.db select * from mysql.new_db;
> ```

**Note:** This option 1 answer was inspired by the [How do I repair an InnoDB table? Advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226172/how-do-i-repair-an-innodb-table/3322930#3322930)

---

### MySQL Won't Start Options

According to some comments on the [Forcing InnoDB Recovery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html) people say setting the `innodb_force_recovery = 1` in the `[mysqld]` section of the `my.cnf` option file before restarting the server will allow you to get it to start if it's failing to start entirely.

Once you get MySQL to start, you could then run the **MySQL Started Option** SQL statements as I listed above, remove the `innodb_force_recovery = 1` afterwards or set it back to the value it was before you changed it, and then restart the MySQL service and see it that resolves the corrupt table data issue.

Another thing to try when you have the `innodb_force_recovery = 1` and the MySQL service started in that mode is to export or backup the corrupt tables (or all databases), and then remove the `innodb_force_recovery = 1` option and restart MySQL and see what happens.

---

### If All Else Fails

You could always transfer another copy of this system from AWS, ensure the swapfile settings are configured accordingly before you start the MySQL service when you get that ready to start from the fresh AWS transfer.

And last but not least, you could always recover your system from the latest [MySQL backup files and such](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-backup.html).

---

### Bonus

I believe this will only apply to `MyISAM` database engine MySQL instances but just in case or someone is looking for such a solution

> In one cmd window ...
>
> ```
> mysqld –-console –-skip-grant-tables –-skip-external-locking
> ```
>
> In another ...
>
> ```
> mysqlcheck –repair mysql user
> ```
>
> If that fails, you may have to restore the mysql db from a backup.
>
> After whichever method fixes the issue, issue mysqladmin shutdown and
>   restart the mysql server normally.
>
> [Source](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,652134,652135#msg-652135)

I believe the `--console` option is for Windows only so if you have trouble with that, simply omit it from the command and use `mysqld –-skip-grant-tables –-skip-external-locking` instead.

- [`–-skip-grant-tables`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqld-options/#-skip-grant-tables)
- [`–-skip-external-locking`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#skip_external_locking)

---

### Further Resources

- [InnoDB Startup Options and System Variables - `innodb_force_recovery`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_force_recovery)
- [InnoDB Backup](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-backup.html)

Comment: @sirryankennedy As per the `InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool` message, it appears the server didn't have enough memory to allocate to the buffer pool. It does seem that the swapfile fix you applied should resolve that though.

Comment: @sirryankennedy I just noticed something you may want to check.... If you run `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;` see if the `ENGINE` for `mysql.db` and `mysql.user` are of the MyISAM and if so, try running the solution based on the **Bonus** section against those tables explicitly i.e `mysqlcheck –repair mysql user` and `mysqlcheck –repair mysql db` The issue may be the `--all-databases` option and running into conflict when tables of non-MyISAM attempted to be run against the tool.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but all of this is a bit over my head. I ran `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;` and it returned 323 rows, but I didn't see MyISAM anywhere. I can connect to MySQL. For the 'Copy and Recreate the mysql.user table' and 'Copy and Recreate the mysql.db table' sections, do I just copy and paste that code in MySQL, or do I change it for certain DBs? Sorry for being a pleb with it comes to MySQL.

Comment: Otherwise, in the topmost section where I write **Copy and Recreate the mysql.user table** run each of those statements one by one, then in the **Copy and Recreate the mysql.db table** run each of those statements one by one. After that is complete, restart the MySQL service and see if the corrupt table error goes away.

Comment: Please note the topmost sections have explicit statements specifying the database and the table names i.e. `mysql.tablename` so you can run those as is with MySQL commands. I guess perhaps this query will tell you if these are `MyISAM` or not `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mysql' AND TABLE_NAME IN ('user', 'db');`.

Comment: I ran the query and indeed, it showed MyISAM for both db and user. But when I ran `mysqld –-console –-skip-grant-tables –-skip-external-locking` with or without --console, it didn't work. It just showed me the 'usage' message. But I followed your instructions to copy and replace mysql.user and mysql.db. Everything seems to be working ok. I will edit my original post to show you the new mysql logs.