# MySQL Cannot access files after backup of data and restore of data

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, mysql

I have a MySQL server running on ubuntu and it somehow got messed up to where I could not access the command line for MySQL anymore.

I reinstalled it but before that I took the folders directly out of `/var/lib/mysql` as to not lose any data and I didnt know of any better way to do it.

Then after reinstallation I put the folders back and everything seemed to work fine but no user of any kind can access the tables of the folders I manually put back.

I’ve tried just changing the files permissions to just `chmod 777` but that did not work. When I try to access it I get the error

```
mysql> select * from galtotals;
ERROR 1017 (HY000): Can't find file: './galf/galtotals.frm' (errno: 13 - Permission denied)
```

Comment: You edited your question to state, “Someone put his question on hold because it was asking too many but the only question I have is about fixing the error above, the beginning is just explaining how I put myself in this situation.” The issue is not you are asking too many questions, but rather the cause and/or solution to this issue can have many disparate answers. From what you describe it all honestly sounds like a mess. The only idea that might help is to suggest you is that you stop MySQL, then find the datafile directory for MySQL and delete `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1`. (1/2)

Comment: Also, while you state that you ran `chmod 777` that is never a good idea. Instead, you should change the permissions of those data directories to match the other MySQL files in that directory. Same owner, same permissions. (2/2)

Comment: It sounds like you need to grant the users access to the databases accordingly as per your restore, you lost the MySQL database permissions. Perhaps backing up this data and having scripts ready to run as root in the event of a restore for quicker reconfiguration will help next time. Start setting up and granting the MySQL database permissions needed for your end-users. Test your backups with a restore when it's not truly needed to learn some of these gotchas. It's not magic, it's backup and restores and practicing and testing the process.

Comment: If you restored and everything is working and data is accessible to root on your select statements or whatever but just not other users connecting, then grant them the access they need and have your process more fine tuned for such scenarios is what I'm saying. For now, keep a log of the grants you run and save to a script or something until you have something more solid moving forward. For the immediate need, grant the people the access they need and hit it from this angle and move forward. Live and learn and especially learn from mistakes.... Best way to learn!!! Du'oh!!!!

Comment: But for some reading and things to try if you are saying root cannot access then .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708409/how-to-start-mysql-with-skip-grant-tables and/or https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2085/how-to-retrieve-granted-privileges-without-access-to-the-database-mysql and/or https://superuser.com/questions/1404549/mysql-crashed-logs-have-many-errors-db-possibly-corrupted/1404635#1404635 may help or give you some ideas to dig into more to help. Once you get the access, check and start granting accordingly if you lost the MySQL database permissions.

Comment: Basically though, you change the mysql config file with certain parameters and then start it up in different modes and such. Dig into it and it can help if you really need it.

Comment: Thank you JakeGould for clearing that up, you are right it is a mess. Thank you @Pimp Juice IT for the help. Giving it to the correct user fixed my issue. also thanks for the tips. However now I have the issue of it saying that the table doesn't exist. should I make another post?

Comment: I would say yes to another post for that. If you do start another post, be detailed with what you have tried, link to this post stating that doing x and x as per the comments people left there helped me resolve that problem, and so forth. Just be sure to keep it to the point, ask one question, and be very clear what your problem is, what you've tried or are struggling with to resolve, and what you need to accomplish but can't because of the problem. I'm glad I helped you resolve the issue, but be sure to write your question in a fashion so it does not get closed like this one.

Comment: I really don't understand what is so broad about this question though. There was a file restore/recovery that was done to the MySQL flat files, and then upon getting those files restored successfully, the database permissions were wiped. This does not seem like a broad problem or too broad to tell what is going on or at least for people that know how MySQL database level permissions work I suppose.